# R dlm library: model definition

Tags: r, matrix, kalman-filter, state-space

I am trying to build a state space model in R using the *dlm* library but keep getting the "incompatible dimensions of matrices" error.

The specifications of the model I am trying to produce are as per below:

Yt = At + beta*Ft + et

Ft = phi1*Ft-1 + phi2*Ft-2 + vt

At = At-1 + wt

where Yt is the observable variable, At is the time varying coefficient modelled as a random walk and Ft is a latent factor which follows an AR(2) process.

I have been trying to set up the FF, V, GG, W, m0 and C0 matrices required by *dlm* to specify the model, but have yet to get the program to work.

Please see below my latest attempt which returns an "incompatible dimensions of matrices" error.

I have traced the relative matrix sizes on paper and they look fine to me. Could anyone please advise where I am going wrong?

```
# the below code works now    
model <- function(x) {
  
  FF <- matrix(c(x[1],0,1), nr=1)
  V  <- matrix(exp(x[2]))
  
  GG <- matrix(c(x[3],1,0,x[4],0,0,0,0,1), nr=3)     
  W  <- diag(c(exp(x[5]),0,exp(x[6])))
  
  m0 <- rep(0,3)
  C0 <- 10*diag(3)
  
  dlm(FF=FF, V=V, GG=GG, W=W, m0=m0,C0=C0)
}
    
# x[1:6] are beta, Var(et), phi1, phi2, Var(vt) and Var(wt)

fit <- dlmMLE(y1, parm = c(rep(0,6)), build = model)

dlmy1 <- model(fit$par)
```

Comment: Share the data for all the variables. I see x, x1, model, ... without data. Besides there is a lone `}` in the code.

Comment: Hi Karthik. Thanks for the reply. I updated the code and added some annotation. Hope it looks clearer now. Variables x[1:6] are parameters to be estimated in the model, while Y is a univariate data set I import from a spreadsheet. I hope to expand this to multivariate analysis in the future. Please let me know should you need more details and thanks again for looking into my post.

Comment: Try replacing 1) `dlm(FF=FF, V=V, GG=GG, W=W, m0=m0,C0=C0)` with `return(list(FF=FF, V=V, GG=GG, W=W, m0=m0,C0=C0))` and 2) `fit <- dlmMLE(Y, parm = c(0,0,0,0), build = model)` with `fit <- dlmMLE(Y, parm = rep(0,6), build = model)` since there are six variables at play. I don't know the technical details of the operations, but this ought to work.

Comment: Thanks Khartik. I played around with the code as per your suggestions and managed to get it working. I updated the original post to reflect the changes made. Thanks again for your help. It is much appreciated.